# Legal to create a backup of website that is shutting down?

Tags: united-states, copyright, website

Is it illegal for me to create a backup of a website that is shutting down, including all assets, etc., and host it on my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the content on the site is copyrighted, and as any logos may be trademarked, it would be illegal to host their content without their permission.

Of course, it may be the case that the site is closing down because it doesn't want to pay for the costs of keeping it going, as such it may something the owners of the site would appreciate if you offer to host their site for free, indefinitely.

Comment: would it be illegal for me to create a copy on my own hard drive if it was never shared with anybody?

Comment: @Vortetty no, you would not be in breach of copyright law so long as you do not distribute that copy.

Comment: @Vortetty moo's comment is incorrect. See my comments to the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

The site is copyrighted so yes, obviously you can not copy it. You can contact them and ask for whatever content you want though.

Comment: It would be a breach of (pretty much any country that has signed the Berne Convention) copyright law to distribute the content, but its not a breach if you simply take a copy for your own private use.  Copyright law is based around unlicensed distribution, not consumption.

Comment: "But its not a breach if you simply take a copy for your own private use. Copyright law is based around unlicensed distribution, not consumption." This isnt true as downloading music or a video game without permission is also copyright infringement, even if you dont distribute it to others. Copyright governs replication, not just distribution. Hence the name "copy"right

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks you are going to have to cite that, because every case brought in a country which follows the Berne Convention involves distribution, not download or replication for personal or archival use.  For example, [Capitol Records vs Thomas-Rasset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitol_Records,_Inc._v._Thomas-Rasset), or [Sony BMG Music Entertainment et al. v. Tenenbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_v._Tenenbaum) - the actual court cases were about making available and distribution.  The Pirate Bay case was about contributory infringement in a similar sense.

Comment: Surely you dont think downloading a video game, movie, or music without the permission of the owner is legal do you? But i will entertain your request

Comment: Firstly I will cover English law as that is the law im trained in: The copyright, designs and patents act 1988 governs the law on copyright. S.16 of the act covers the "acts restricted by copyright in a work". S.16(1) states "the owner of the copyright in a work has...the exclusive right to do the following acts in the United Kingdom"...s16(1)(a) [the right] to copy  the work"

Comment: The word exclusive is key here, as that means no one but the owner of the copyright may do the exclusive act of copying his work. It is by virtue of this law that music piracy, video game piracy etc. is illegal in the UK

Comment: A basic overview of these rights can be found at https://www.gov.uk/copyright. The page repeats what is mentioned above: "copyright prevents people from...copying your work".

Comment: Regarding US law, section 106 of the copyright law of the US (https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#106A) clearly states: "the owner of copyright has the exclusive rights to do or authorise any of the following: (1) to reproduce the copyrighted work

Comment: The reason why most cases of regarding infringement involve unauthorised distribution is because thats where a company is likely to incur damages (if someone else if distributing your product instead of you, this costs you sales), as such there is a greater incentive to prevent unauthorised distribution than there is for unauthorised replication/copying.

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks as far as I remember there were some exemptions, specifically that you were allowed to make one copy of a legally owned copyrighted material for backup purpose? Not sure about the US, but I remember something like that in EU copyright legislation.

Comment: There are also fair use exceptions. But I'm not saying exceptions don't exist, they certainly do. Moo's point was that copyright covers distribution without permission but not private copying without permission

Comment: @Moo It is still a breach of copyright, even if no one prosecutes you for it. This is like the age old question "if a tree falls in the forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?" With copyright and the law, the answer is 'yes', even if no one prosecutes you and no one could possibly know that you made more than one copy for 'archival' purposes. In practical terms this means that almost everyone who has the habit of clicking "Save As..." and so on, or saving copies of downloaded files on various media more than once, is probably in violation of the law.